# How to check JSON can be converted to dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, guard

[image]

Tried this, but get error:

```
var d = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as [String: String]
guard let d2 = d else {
    return
}
```

Comment: `as?` with a question mark. But `[String: Any]` might be better. Note that `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers` is useless with Swift Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right tool here is JSONDecoder, not JSONSerialization:

```
let d = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, data)
```

`.mutableContainers` doesn't make sense when converting to a Swift Dictionary. That causes it to create `NSMutableDictionary` objects, which will just be converted to `[String: String]` exactly the same as without `.mutableContainers` (but possibly with an extra copy step).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
guard let dic = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String]  else { return }
```

Comment: Hi! Why need `?` in `try?`?